# AbsoluteTime type not imported into Swift

Tags: xcode, swift, types, compiler-errors, iokit

The Swift compiler seems very confused when trying to use the AbsoluteTime type for IOKit HID code.

This block compiles and runs fine, printing "UnsignedWide".

```
import IOKit.hid

var event = IOHIDEventStruct()
let timestamp = event.timestamp
let lo: UInt32 = timestamp.lo
let hi: UInt32 = timestamp.hi
let newTime = event.timestamp.dynamicType.init(lo: lo, hi: hi)
event.timestamp = newTime
print(timestamp.dynamicType)
```

This, however, does not compile.

```
let time1: AbsoluteTime = event.timestamp

"error: use of undeclared type 'AbsoluteTime'"
```

This also does not compile.

```
let wide1: UnsignedWide = event.timestamp

"error: use of undeclared type 'UnsignedWide'"
```

This fails to compile as well, but that's expected.

```
let uint: UInt64 = event.timestamp

"error: cannot convert value of type 'AbsoluteTime' (aka 'UnsignedWide') to specified type 'UInt64'"
```

So since Swift clearly knows that UnsignedWide is a struct with two UInt32 fields, I figured I'd try just defining my own struct with those qualities, but this fails as well.

```
struct UnsignedWide {
    let lo: UInt32
    let hi: UInt32
}
typealias AbsoluteTime = UnsignedWide
let time2: AbsoluteTime = event.timestamp
let wide2: UnsignedWide = event.timestamp

"error: cannot convert value of type 'AbsoluteTime' (aka 'UnsignedWide') to specified type 'AbsoluteTime' (aka 'UnsignedWide')" 
"error: cannot convert value of type 'AbsoluteTime' (aka 'UnsignedWide') to specified type 'UnsignedWide'"
```

This works, at least.

```
let time3: AbsoluteTime = unsafeBitCast(event.timestamp, AbsoluteTime.self)
```

I'd rather not do that though, and I can only create AbsoluteTime variables with this ugliness.

```
let AbsoluteTime = event.timestamp.dynamicType
let time4 = AbsoluteTime.init(lo: lo, hi: hi)
```

Unfortunately, that doesn't let me use AbsoluteTime as a type in functions or struct or anything like that, so that doesn't really solve my problem.

This is the case with Xcode 7.3 and the Xcode 7.3.1 GM.

Anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Darwin.UnsignedWide` which is aliased by `AbsoluteTime`

E.g.:

This compiles:

```
import Darwin

public protocol CurrentAbsoluteTimeProvider: class {
    func currentAbsoluteTime() -> Darwin.AbsoluteTime
}
```

This fails to compile:

```
import Darwin

public protocol CurrentAbsoluteTimeProvider: class {
    func currentAbsoluteTime() -> AbsoluteTime
}
```

I've added this file to my library that uses IOKit: https://github.com/avito-tech/Mixbox/blob/e3a5991f61dd2a36e13193e67ca69743f5bb62c7/Frameworks/Foundation/CurrentAbsoluteTimeProvider/AbsoluteTime/AbsoluteTime.swift

By the way, our company is developing a Swift library for working with IOKit. Permalink: https://github.com/avito-tech/Mixbox/tree/e3a5991f61dd2a36e13193e67ca69743f5bb62c7/Frameworks/IoKit